# Pocketsphinx не видит слово в словаре

Tags: python, pocketsphinx

Есть проект на **Python** для распознавания речи с использованием **pocketsphinx**. Был сгенерирован свой словарь и файл грамматики. Однако возникает ошибка

```
RuntimeError: new_Decoder returned -1
```

А из детализации узнаем, что

```
ERROR: "fsg_search.c", line 141: The word 'экран' is missing in the dictionary
```

Однако слово "экран" есть в словаре.

Подскажите, как решить эту проблему?

Спасибо

---

Файл грамматики

```
#JSGF V1.0;
grammar commands;
<action> = (включить | выключить | опустить | поднять);
<device> = (проектор | экран | звук | презентацию);
public <commands> = <action> <device>;
```

Словарь

```
включить v k ll uj ch i tt
выключить v y k ll uj ch ii tt
проектор p r ay i k t oo r
экран eh k r ay n
звук z v uu k
опустить a p u ss tt ii tt
поднять p a d nn ja tt
презентацию p rr i zz i n t aa c y uj
```